# PHP - Accessing Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to access a file from google cloud storage with PHP

A colleague who manages GCS gave me a json key file `gcs_key.json`.

I tried the following:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFilePath' => '../web/gcs_key.json'
]);
```

But am getting an error saying:

```
Class 'Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient' not found
```

I have installed the necessary packages with composer as shown here:

```
composer require google/cloud

Key require is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 9
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^0.176.0 for google/cloud
./composer.json has been updated
Key require is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 9
Running composer update google/cloud
Loading composer repositories with package information
Package "google/cloud" listed for update is not locked.
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files

composer require google/cloud-storage

Key require is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 9
Using version ^1.26 for google/cloud-storage
./composer.json has been updated
Key require is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 9
Running composer update google/cloud-storage
Loading composer repositories with package information
Package "google/cloud-storage" listed for update is not locked.
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have more than one **vendor/autoload.php** file in different locations? Post your composer.json.

Comment: @JohnHanley No other vendor folder on the system. composer.json is: {
    "require": {
        "gettext/gettext": "^5.5",
        "google/cloud-storage": "^1.26",
        "google/cloud": "^0.176.0",
  "sendgrid/sendgrid": "~7"
 }
}

Comment: Please edit your question. Do not add content in comments as that is too hard to read and how text is formatted often matters.

Comment: As John Hanley mentioned please update the composer.json file in question. Also did you  commit the composer.lock file to your application? You can refer the URL for details https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md